# JsonSchema2Pojo and manual task in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jsonschema2pojo

**What I would like to achieve**

I would like to have a manual gradle task that I can generate Java classes based on Json schema. However, I don't want this task to run when I run other fx. *gradle build*.

**What I did**

Firstly I've create simple gradle java project with

```
gradle init
```

Then I  have added *jsonschema2dataclass* plugin and configure it as follows (my current build.gradle):

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 * (...) 
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    id 'application'

    id "org.jsonschema2dataclass" version "4.5.0"
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Use JUnit Jupiter API for testing.
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.2'

    // Use JUnit Jupiter Engine for testing.
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'

    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'GradlePlayground.App'
}

jsonSchema2Pojo {
            includeGeneratedAnnotation = true
            generateBuilders = true
            targetPackage = 'org.example.api' // specify package for your needs
            targetDirectoryPrefix = file("${project.rootDir}/app/src/main/java")

            source.setFrom files("${project.rootDir}/app/src/main/resources/json")
}
```

**What I've tried**

1. Add `task.enabled = false`
2. Put plugin configuration into another task
3. Check source code of plugin to find a way to disconnect this task from build task

But all above trails have failed. When I run gradle tasks I can always see `generateJsonSchema2DataClass` and `generateJsonSchema2DataClass0` as part of build tasks.

I'm using java 8 and gradle 6.9.3

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the gradle plugin.

Short answer for your question is "no, it's not an intended flow for a normal project". However, it's always possible to create a new project, build it once and extract the sources.

Could you please explain, what the reason you want to exclude run from the `build` chain?

My only guess is to build and publish models. And if this is a case, it's possible to do this using some gradle magic, which described in discussions in the [GitHub project](https://github.com/jsonschema2dataclass/js2d-gradle/discussions/451)

**UPD:** Based on your gradle script, I have a lot of "why" questions I'd like to ask, it'll be easier if you

Comment: for me the use-case is, running generateJson2Pojo task removes the license from the classes so I want to control on dev environment to not to trigger whenever gradle build is triggerered
`ps: Thanks for the plugin ! appreciate ur effort on this.`

Comment: Could you please to create an issue for the project? I want to understand better your situation

Comment: I dont' understand "taks removes the license from the classes", so could you please create another question or an issue